# Adding constant in the results from a multiple SQL Server join

Tags: sql-server, join, constants

I have four tables to join and I need to identify which table the data is coming from in a column within the results. I join Tbl1 to Tbl2 using left outer join. I join Tbl1 to Tbl3 using left outer join and same with Tbl1 to Tbl 4. SerialNo is the key field I join all tables by. The results needs to indicate which table the data came from. For matching results between tables I want the right table to be identified. For example, in my sample tables I want to show that Tbl2 is in the results for those records where SerialNo is ABC123, DEF987 and HJK321.

Because of how the data will be extract from the database I'm unable to initiate a stored procedure so I'm planning on having a view to pull the data from, unless I can utilize a temp table in the process.

```
Tbl1
*Hostname*  | *SerialNo*
Laptop1     | ABC123
Laptop2     | DEF987
Desktop1    | WER987
Desktop2    | YRT848
Desktop3    | YTT876
Laptop2     | HJK321

Tbl2
*Location*  | *SerialNo*
MS      | ABC123
CO      | DEF987
CA      | ZYC342
AZ      | XYZ789
IN      | HJK321
```

What I'd like to see in the results...

```
Result1
*Hostname*  | *SerialNo*    |*Location* |*RecordOrigin*
Laptop1     | ABC123        |MS         |Tbl2
Laptop2     | DEF987        |CO         |Tbl2
Desktop1    | WER987        |NULL       |Tbl1
Desktop2    | YRT848        |NULL       |Tbl1
Desktop3    | YTT876        |NULL       |Tbl1
Laptop2     | HJK321        |IN         |Tbl2
```

I tried creating an additional table for RecordOrigin information, but I wasn't able to join to the other tables correctly.

I'm should also note that I'm not able to edit the data in, or change the structure of, the source tables tables (i.e. Tbl1, Tbl2, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression to see if a table is returning a column or not like so:

```
select 
    t.Hostname
  , t.SerialNo
  , l.Location
  , RecordOrigin = case 
      when l.SerialNo is not null 
        then 'Tbl2' 
      else 'Tbl1' 
      end
from Tbl1 as t
  left join Tbl2 as l
    on t.SerialNo = l.SerialNo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figured it out by UNION the tables and using DISTINCT and MAX to remove duplication.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Hostname,  MAX(SerialNo), MAX(Location), RecordOrigin
FROM
(
SELECT Hostname, SerialNo, Location, 'Tbl1' AS RecordOrigin
FROM Tbl1

UNION

SELECT Hostname, SerialNo, Location, 'Tbl2' AS RecordOrigin
FROM Tbl1
)
GROUP BY Hostname, RecordOrigin
```